# Function with string as return type in C

Tags: c, function, return-type

I needed a function to return a string. I used the following code to declare the function:

```
const char* serv_con(char app_data[50])
{
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
    //i am avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
    return recv_data;
}
```

and then called the function in the main like this:

```
int main()
{
    char ser_data[50], app_data[50];
    ser_data[0] = '\0';
    app_data[0] = '\0';
    //avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
    app_data = serv_con(ser_data); //function call
}
```

On compiling it gives the error:

```
connect.c:109: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[50]’ from type ‘const char *’
```

Then i replaced the *const char* in the declaration with std::string. The declaration now is as follows:

```
std::string serv_con(char app_data[50])
{
    char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
    //avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
    return recv_data;
}
```

And called it in the same way as mentioned above. But still it gives the following error on compiling:

```
connect.c:13: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token
```

Please tell me how I can give a string as a return type from a function. The platform I work on is linux. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't C++. Don't tag it C++.

Comment: Why are you using const? It means values cannot be modified. and you are still trying to modify it somewhere in the code.

Comment: I avoided the `const` and tried with `char*`, but still it gives the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
const char* serv_con(char app_data[50])
{
  char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
  //i am avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
  return recv_data;
}
```

this cannot work, since you're returning a pointer to a local variable, which is invalid after returning. You need to allocate `recv_data` on the heap in order to use it after returning

```
char* serv_con(char app_data[50])
{
  char send_data[1024];
  char *recv_data = malloc(1024);
  if (!recv_data)
      return NULL;

  // ...
  return recv_data;
 }
```

then change the main function to be something like

```
int main()
{
 char ser_data[50];
 char *app_data;
 ser_data[0] = '\0';
 //avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
 app_data = serv_con(ser_data); //function call
 if (!app_data) {
   // error
 }
}
```

Comment: But i need the string `app_data` to be blank initially. How can I do that?

Comment: it not will contain any data and will be invalid before the call to `serv_con()`. if you need to use `app_data` before, you may need an additional variable for storing the return-value of `serv_con()` or just free `app_data` before calling `serv_con()`.

Comment: I have done as you said. Now all the errors are gone but I still get this warning: `connect.c:107: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type`. If this a problem?

Comment: Could you post line 107 from `connect.c`?

Comment: is it possible that you still have `serv_con()` defined as `const char *` ? That would explain the warning.

Comment: It is the function call `app_data = serv_con(ser_data);`

Comment: Just define `serv_con()` as `char * serv_con(char app_data[50])` and the warning will be gone

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is a really bad idea.  The `serv_con` function allocates some space on the stack for the `recv_data` array and then returns a pointer to that location.  Of course, as soon as you call another function that data will be wiped out, leading to a bug that is difficult to diagnose.  If you must return a block of memory from a function, allocate it using `malloc`.  Basically, never return pointers to objects on the stack.

When you get the pointer out of `serv_con` you assign it to `app_data`, which already has some space allocated.  There is no reason for doing this: simply declare `app_data` as a `char *` that will point to the storage allocated in `serv_con`.

Answer (score 1):

Returning pointer to local array or the array itself is a bad idea.

Even if you do malloc inside the function, the caller needs to free that memory too which is again not a very good practice.

I suggest the best way is to pass an out parameter i.e. pass the array in which you want the result to be copied as a parameter.

```
int serv_con(char app_data[50], char recv_data[50])
{
    char send_data[1024];
     //recv_data[1024];
    //i am avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.
    return 1; // return status success or failure which can be tested in main
}
```

and then called the function in the main like this:

```
int main()
{
    char ser_data[50], app_data[50];
    ser_data[0] = '\0';
    app_data[0] = '\0';
    //avoiding code segments irrelevant to the issue.

    serv_con(ser_data, app_data); //function call
}
```

I found and corrected a slight mistake. The app_data you are passing in main is of size 50 where as the one you were trying to return from the function serv_con was 1024. This should be consistent. I have used both of size 50 in code above.

Comment: Your comments about allocating memory inside a function and freeing it outside is perfect. But is there a way where we can write a function that takes a char array, processes that and produce a output ( the length of this output array varies depending on the input). Here the output array size is dynamic, so is there a possibility to handle such cases. *Allocating and freeing the output array before and after the function call, from the point of invocation might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can be pretty sure that you are a beginner. Please go through a good text book i.e [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

Along with the error you must be getting this.
warning: function returns address of local variable.

Look at the warnings always. The question is already answered by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/163956/greg-inozemtsev).